# How to test Gradle plugin that sets up custom repositories?

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, spock, gradle-plugin

I have a custom Gradle plugin written in Java that sets up custom Maven repositories, among other things:

```java
    project.getRepositories().maven(repository -> {
        repository.setName(NAME);
        repository.setUrl(URL);
        repository.mavenContent(MavenRepositoryContentDescriptor::releasesOnly);
    });
```

I now work on integration tests (using Spock and Groovy), where I basically do `project.getPluginManager().apply(CustomPlugin.class)` and check that the `Project` instance is set up correctly.

My problem with testing the above logic is the `::releasesOnly` bit:

```
def "repositories are set up correctly"() {
    given:
    def repositories = project.repositories

    expect:
    repositories.size() == 1
    repositories[0] instanceof DefaultMavenArtifactRepository
    def repoReleases = repositories[0] as DefaultMavenArtifactRepository
    repoReleases.name == NAME
    repoReleases.url.toString() == URL
    // How to test whether the repository will be used only to fetch releases and not snapshots?
}
```

**The question is**: how to test whether the repository will be used only to fetch releases and not snapshots?

So far my thoughts are:

1. Spy on `repositories` and make sure the correct lambda is applied.
   It will get a bit tricky, but should work.
   The problem I see with this approach is that I test the implementation instead of testing the requirement.
2. I could just skip testing this line.
   It's highly unlikely that accidentally deleting it would introduce critical bugs.
   This would be practical, though not exactly *right*.
3. The 'best' way seems to be to prompt the `Project` instance to search for dependencies and observe the behavior.
   But so far, even knowing Gradle a bit, I'm not sure how to concisely (and locally) simulate this.

Can someone suggest the least painful way of implementing the third scenario, or perhaps point out why some other approach is preferable?

Comment: This sound like you are trying to re-test gradle functionality, I would advice against doing that.

Comment: @LeonardBrünings I did consider whether I’m trying to test Gradle instead of my own code. I guess I do come close to that.